# How to know if an application is idle

Tags: delphi

I'm creating a framework for simulating user inputs (mouse and keys).

This framework will provide an API for simple implementation of DUnit tests.

One of my big problems currently is about waiting for the application to be idle.

I have a server (TCP) that receives commands like "type text", "press keys", "click at XY"... and I need to WAIT for these commands to be processed and then return to the client API to continue running the next step of the test.

Since my server receives and executes the actions through a thread, it does not run the risk of catching the executions, as in the case of clicking a button that will display a modal message.

I'm currently using the ApplicationEvents.OnIdle to assist me, but in some cases it doesn't work very well.

I also tried using the WaitForInputIdle but only it does not solve my problem, because the application may still be processing the action after processing the User Input...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Sounds like you should stop running long operations in the main thread and wean yourself off `Application.ProcessMessages`

Comment: The design of your program could be that it starts some action, and then may either (a) use threads, and be in progress on a bunch of background items, or (b) use a long blocking operation in the main thread with a bunch of Application.ProcessMessages calls.  So if it's your own apps you're doing this for, I suggest that you implement a trace message system and actually explicitly state in that trace message system: "Action:SaveFile:Complete".  And then have the external program read this trace-log.  You could use named pipes or sockets, or even write a log file to disk.

Answer (score 0):

How are you simulating user input? Are you feeding the program messages via PostMessage? If so, you could swap to SendMessage, which blocks until the program's processed the sent message.

Comment: No, I can't use the sendmessage precisely not to block execution...
I would need to know when the application is no longer processing anything ...

Comment: SendMessage blocks the current thread, so this should be something you could solve with threads.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in control of the *target* application (I assume this because you mention the ApplicationEvents' OnIdle event), I would look into RegisterWindowMessage, and have a message respond (e.g. pass a HWND of the test-system as LParam or WParam) when the application is no longer running anything.

Because the custom messages are queued in the central message queue, you should get a response as soon as the application completes its operation you started by simlulating input events.

Comment: This custom message will be enqueued at the end of list?

Comment: A keypress or clicks can generate other messages like WM_PAINT... this messages will be processed before my custom message? I think not...